# placing flash object alongside with another div

Tags: javascript, html, flash, web, swfobject

I have a flash object which is 300x600. I want to place it horizontally with another div. swfObject creates it with `style="display: block !important;"`, so I think that's the problem.

I've tried to use `swfobject.createCSS` to disable this, but it didn't work-out.

I'd be glad for help.

Comment: So basically you would want to keep two divs side by side and in one div you will place a flash object ?

Comment: @cafebabe1991, exactly.

Comment: Have a look at the answer below

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do it ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#wrapper {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
}
#first {
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#second {
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin: 0 0 0 302px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
       <div id="first">
           <object width="300" height="315"
                data="http://www.youtube.com/v/XGSy3_Czz8k">
           </object>
       </div>
       <div id="second">
           <h1>This is some second div</h1>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```